# HTML2Canvas - Chrome Issue - Undefined

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, html2canvas

I am trying to use HTML2Canvas to grab the content of a div and save it as an image. This works perfectly in Firefox but Chrome is throwing up an error. I am including the HTML2Canvas JS file above my build.js file.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
function genImage(callback) {

// Hide the Plus + Minus Buttons
$('.expandImage').hide();
$('.shrinkImage').hide();

html2canvas($(".templateDesign"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {

        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
             var formdata = new FormData();
             formdata.append("image", blob);

            return $.ajax({
                url: "imageupload.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).success(callback);
        });
    }
});
}
```

The function is run when a button is clicked. As I say, it works perfectly in Firefox. However in Chrome I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function build.js:234html2canvas.onrendered build.js:234o.complete html2canvas-min.js:2o html2canvas-min.js:1e.onload html2canvas-min.js:1
```

Any ideas why Chrome isn't working but FireFox is?

Answer (score 0):

Realised toBlob is not supported in Chrome. Used the following to get it working:

https://github.com/eligrey/canvas-toBlob.js